# Bootstrap CSS hides a portion of a container below navbar navbar-fixed-top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a project with Bootstrap and I'm facing a little issue. I have a container below the Nav-top. My issue is that some portion of my container is hidden below the nav-top header.I don't want to use top-margin with the container. Please see the below HTML in which I'm facing the issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
           <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
                <div class="nav-collapse"><ul class="nav" id="navbar"><li ng-class="{active:section=='plunks'}" class="active"><a href="/plunks/trending"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li><li><a target="_self" href="/edit/"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>General Election 2014</a></li><li class="divider-vertical">
                    </li><li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-eye-open">
                        </i>Assembly Elections
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/HTML5Apps">Assembly Elections 2013</a></li>
                        </ul>
                         </li><li class="divider-vertical">
                    </li><li ng-class="{active:section=='tags'}"><a href="/tags"><i class="icon-th"></i>Constituecy</a></li><li ng-class="{active:section=='discuss'}"><a href="/discuss"><i class="icon-time"></i>Election News</a></li><li class="divider-vertical"></li><li><a href="https://github.com/filearts/plunker"><i class="icon-bell"></i>Candidate</a></li></ul></div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  <div  class="container" >
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Popular</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Collapse.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the bootstrap docs: Fixed to top
Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the <body>. Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

This is handled by adding some `padding` to the top of the `<body>`.

As per [Bootstrap's documentation on `.navbar-fixed-top`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top), *try out your own values or use our snippet below.* Tip: By default, the `navbar` is `50px` high.

```
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
```

Also, take a look at the source for [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) and open [`starter-template.css`](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css).

Comment: i added 60px padding between responsive css and normal css and it worked fine

Comment: the issue is.. if I customize the bootstrap via customize link.. then I don't get responsive css separately... so there is no way to provide this "between" the two declarations. 

Also this add-some-tag-between-my-normal-and-responsive-css advice.. seems bit of hackish. Doesn't it? There has to be better solution than this.

Comment: If you are using LESS, use bootstrap variable @navbar-height to find the navbar height.

Comment: This is more of a work-around than a solution: While this helps with the top of the page, anchors and such still don't work. If you scroll to a subsection using anchors, the title of the subsection will be behind the navigation bar.

Comment: why does this start happening to begin with does anyone know? it just started happening to me which felt like out of nowhere and i still can't find the source of what broke it to begin with.

Answer (score 41):

I guess the problem you have is related to the dynamic height that the fixed **navbar** at the top has.  For example, when a user logs in, you need to display some kind of "*Hello [User Name]*" and when the name is too wide, the **navbar** needs to use more height so this text doesn't overlap with the **navbar** menu.  As the **navbar** has the style "*position: fixed*", the body stays underneath it and a taller part of it becomes hidden so you need to "dynamically" change the padding at the top every time the **navbar** height changes which would happen in the following case scenarios:

1. The page is loaded / reloaded.
2. The browser window is resized as this could hit a different responsive breakpoint.
3. The **navbar** content is modified directly or indirectly as this could provoke a height change.

This dynamicity is not covered by regular *CSS* so I can only think of one way to solve this problem if the user has *JavaScript* enabled.  Please try the following *jQuery* code snippet to resolve case scenarios 1 and 2; for case scenario 3 please remember to call the function *onResize()* after any change in the **navbar** content:

```js
var onResize = function() {
  // apply dynamic padding at the top of the body according to the fixed navbar height
  $("body").css("padding-top", $(".navbar-fixed-top").height());
};

// attach the function to the window resize event
$(window).resize(onResize);

// call it also when the page is ready after load or reload
$(function() {
  onResize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Optimized it by storing window width and checking if only vertical resize has changed.

Answer (score 20):

Just define an empty navbar prior to the fixed one, it will create the space needed.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
</nav>
<nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
     <div class="container-fluid">
// Your menu code 
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is a nasty way of doing things.

Comment: Close, but doesn't account for wrapping of items in the real navbar - unless you duplicate all of the menu there.

Comment: Agree with @DotSlashCoding, this approach is not good coding practice (fails maintainability test for no good reason). It isn't clear right away what this extra `navbar` does.

Comment: Pragmatic and cool. I also think that all solutions to this issue are nasty.

Answer (score 9):

It happens because with `navbar-fixed-top` class the navbar gets the `position:fixed`. This in turns take the navbar out of the document flow leaving the body to take up the space *behind* the navbar.

You need to apply `padding-top` or `margin-top` to your `container`, based on your requirements with values `>= 50px`. (or play around with different values)

The basic bootstrap **navbar** takes height around **`40px`**. So if you give a `padding-top` or `margin-top` of **`50px`**  or more, you will always have that breathing space between your *container and the navbar.*

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 and want navbar at top then replace `fixed-top` with `sticky-top`.

Problem solved of hidden data under navbar.

Comment: It worked with bootstrap 4. Thank you a lot.

Comment: sticky-top shows the navbar correctly, but then it is not fixed

Answer (score 6):

I too have had this problem but solved it without script and only using CSS.  I start by following the recommended padding-top for a fixed menu by setting of 60px described on the Bootstrap website.  Then I added three media tags that resize the padding at the cutoff points where my menu also resizes.

```
<style>      
    body{
        padding-top:60px;
    }
    /* fix padding under menu after resize */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body { padding-top: 60px; }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        body { padding-top: 110px; }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        body { padding-top: 60px; }
    }
</style>
```

One note, when my menu width is between 768 and 991, the menu logo in my layout plus the `<li>` options cause the menu to wrap to two lines.  Therefore, I had to adjust the padding-top to prevent the menu from covering the content, hence 110px.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 6):

I know this thread is old, but i just got into that exactly problem and i fixed it by just using the `page-header` class in my page, under the nav. Also i used the `<nav>` tag instead of `<div>` but i am not sure it would present any different behavior.

Using the `page-header` as a container for the page, you won't need to mess with the `<body>`, only if you disagree with the default space that the `page-header` gives you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



   <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Registration form <br /><small>A Bootstrap template showing a registration form with standard fields</small></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="well well-sm"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Required Field</strong></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputName">Enter Name</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputEmail">Enter Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmailFirst" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputEmail">Confirm Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmailSecond" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Confirm Email" required>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputMessage">Enter Message</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

i solved it using jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var h = $('nav').height() + 20;
   $('body').animate({ paddingTop: h });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy:

Code (JS)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
          navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight; //get the offset height
          document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px'; // Add the offset height to the top padding
   });
```

StackOverflow throws an error due to the class navbar not existing.